# Replace all left spaces with a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have following code to replace left spaces with a specific string but, It is not working as I want.

```js
console.log('  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd'.replace(/^\s+/, 'x'))
```

It changed all left spaces with x, but It should change every left spaces with one x.

But I just need this output:

`xxasdadasdad as asdasd asasd`

How can I do it ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This will surely do in two lines:

```
  var str ='   asdadasdad as asdasd asasd';   
  console.log(str.trim().padStart(str.length, 'x'));
```

Comment: Might want to do `trimStart()` if you only want to change the first spaces and leave any extra spaces at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
.replace(/\s/gy, 'x')
```

Here, each whitespace that is at the start of the string is replaced with `x`. The combination of the `g` (global) and `y` (sticky) modifiers makes it match at the start of the string, and then consecutively until no match is found.

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
  '  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd'.replace(/\s/gy, 'x')
)
```

Comment: Is the *sticky* modifier (great name) unique to Javascript's regex engine?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I do not remember any other regex engine that uses a specific modifier for this, but it is similar to a `\G` operator in PCRE/Onigmo and the like when it is  used at the start of the regex (in Ruby, [`s.gsub(/\G\s/, 'x')`](https://ideone.com/9PsBVJ))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function to generate the same length string which contains `x`.

```js
console.log('  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd'.replace(/^\s+/, m => new Array(m.length).fill('x').join('')))
```

---

Or alternately with positive look-behind(not supported widely, [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#bcd:javascript.builtins.RegExp)).

```js
    console.log('  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd'.replace(/(?<=^\s*)\s/g, 'x'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome solution.

Comment: Your link for #2 refers only to whether browsers support look-behinds. Can we assume that all that support look-behinds support variable-length look-behinds? The ECMAScript engine at regex101.com supports variable-length look-behinds, rare among regex engines generally.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a lambda function as 2nd argument of `.replace`:

```js
const s = '  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd';

var repl = s.replace(/^\s+/, m => m.replace(/\s/g, 'x'));

console.log(repl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're replacing complete match with single `x` character but you need to repeat `x` to length of match,

```js
let str = '  asdadasdad as asdasd asasd'
let replacedStr = str.replace(/^\s+/, (m) => 'x'.repeat(m.length))
console.log(replacedStr)
```

Comment: Thanks for that great solution.

Comment: @Jeremy always happy to help. don't forgot to upvote and select as correct answer whichever you feel helped you most :)