# Replace the first repeated instance of a character

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a simple one that I can't seem to find an answer for.  I have:

```
let a = '1111Some1text1or1something'
```

And I'm trying to achieve:

```
'2222Some1text1or1something'
```

I put the characters as numbers for clarity, really I'm trying to replace spaces.  Anyway notice that it only replaces every instance of a single character at the beginning.  It will stop replacing when it reaches a `\w`

Almost all google searches have lead me to answers about "reduce repeated characters" and the like, but I'm looking to "replace all instances of a character until the first word"

```
a.replace(/^[1]*/, '2')
```

Will crush up all the repeated characters into a single.

Comment: `a.replace(/1/gy, '2')`. With ECMAScript 2018+ JS environments, you may even use ``a.replace(/(?<=^1*)1/g, '2')``

Comment: Try this:

`(.)\1+`

Matches the same text as most recently matched in the first (`\1`) capture group.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ovYhYN/1/

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I would love to use that one but "sticky" is not IE11 compatible.  I'd give you credit anyway since IE11 is garbage.  Unfortunately I'm in IE11 land so no go for that.

Comment: @lux that seems to replace all as a single "find".  So this would crush down the repeated pattern.  However that is a cool thing to know about, just not working in my case.

Comment: Ok, then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918401/3832970, just replace `\s+` with `1+`

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to skin the cat. Here is one with a replace function, where `p1` contains the 1s, and are replaced by 2s:

```js
var str = '1111Some1text1or1something'
var result = str.replace(/^(1*)/, function(m, p1) {
  return p1.replace(/1/g, '2')
});
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Console.log:

```
result: 2222Some1text1or1something
```

Comment: Yeah this pattern was my last ditch effort.  I went with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918745/358748

Answer (score -1):

You can specify function as a second argument of `replace` and use match length to generate replacement with proper length.

```
"1111Some1text1or1something".replace(/^[1]*/, (match) => '2'.repeat(match.length))
```